# Can't convert vcxproj to cmake with the cmake-converter

Tags: command-line, compiling, c++, cmake

I am using the `cmake-converter` tool from [this](https://cmakeconverter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/use.html) link to convert a `.vcxproj` file to cmake to be able to use it with Clion.  I am in the folder where the vcxproj file is located and I run the following command:

`cmake-converter -p in_lab.vcxproj`

And I get the following error from my terminal:

```
usage: cmake-converter -s <path/to/file.sln> [ -h | -p | -d | -v | -w | -j | -a ]
cmake-converter: error: the following arguments are required: -s/--solution
```

I have tried those arguments previously and they threw index errors.  How should I go about converting my file to cmake?

Comment: Possible off-topic question. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS was released 2014.April (thus 14.04) with 5 years of supported life, and is now EOL & thus off-topic unless questions are specific to moving to a supported release. Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is supported by Canonical directly & off-topic here too. (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @guiverc Fixed it